# dynamic address and unknown file name for html5 mp3player like code below

Tags: javascript, php, html, media-player, flash

As you can see below the code that I have is fully functional for reading an uploaded mp3 file from user and then pass it for flash player to play it.

```
if($uplfile !="")
    $url = $my_base_url.$my_website_base."/modules/upload/attachments/".$uplfile;
else    
    $url = $this->get_template_vars('enc_url');

$info = pathinfo($url);

if ($info["extension"] == "mp3") 
{
{/php} 

<center>  
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="{$my_base_url}{$my_website_base}/templates/{$the_template}/img/player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="200" height="20">
    <param name="movie" value="{$my_base_url}{$my_website_base}/templates/{$the_template}/img/player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
{php}   
echo '    <param name="FlashVars" value="'.urldecode($url).'" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3='.$url.'&amp;showstop=1&amp;showinfo=1&amp;showvolume=1" />
</object>  

</center>';
```

However I want to use html5 player instead. I would say something like this.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src=" **? Don't Know What to put ?** " type="audio/ogg">
  <source src=" **? Don't Know What to put ?** " type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
```

I tried all the possible thing to use for source in order to read the file but still could not to do so. Please be advise that I don't the filename and is unknown and will be uploaded by user.
Thanks in advance. this is the first time I'm using this website so please ignore if I didn't follow exactly the rules for asking question.

EDIT

I used the following code
I kept both the HTML5 and the javascript to see which one will work. I want to get rid of the swf flash which is working because of compatibility with mobile devices.

```
{php}
global $db,$my_base_url,$my_pligg_base;
$lid = $this->get_template_vars('link_id');
$uplfile = $db->get_var("select file_name from ".table_prefix."files where file_link_id='".$lid."'  and file_size='orig'");


if($uplfile !="")
    $url = $my_base_url.$my_pligg_base."/modules/upload/attachments/".$uplfile;
else    
    $url = $this->get_template_vars('enc_url');

$info = pathinfo($url);

if ($info["extension"] == "mp3") 
{
{/php} 
<audio controls>
  <source src=" $url " type="audio/ogg">
  <source src=" $url" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
function music(track){
   $('#audioPlayer').attr('src', track);
   $('#audioPlayer').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
   $.get();
   }

function pauseAudio(){
   $('#audioPlayer').get(0).pause();
   }
   </script>
<img alt="" onclick="music('http://www.raphmond.com/modules/upload/attachments/'); return false;" src="http://www.raphmond.com/templates/coolstrap/img/play.png"> 
<img alt="" onclick="pauseAudio(); return false;" src="http://www.raphmond.com/templates/coolstrap/img/pause.png"> 

<audio id="audioPlayer" src=""></audio>


<center>  
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="{$my_base_url}{$my_pligg_base}/templates/{$the_template}/img/player_mp3_maxi.swf" width="200" height="20">
    <param name="movie" value="{$my_base_url}{$my_pligg_base}/templates/{$the_template}/img/player_mp3_maxi.swf" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
{php}   
echo '    <param name="FlashVars" value="'.urldecode($url).'" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3='.$url.'&amp;showstop=1&amp;showinfo=1&amp;showvolume=1" />

</object>  

</center>';
```

Comment: You are not specifying a file in your path, in the `music()` function call on the onclick event. You've got `http://www.raphmond.com/modules/upload/attachments/`, which should be `http://www.raphmond.com/modules/upload/attachments/myfile.mp3`

Comment: The file is not known. Each time the user drop the mp3 it will be placed in that folder. As you see in the swf version, the file name is not used. This web site will accept the uploaded mp3 by users and then make a block for it and play it. its not possible to put the "file name".

Comment: Well, you are using a php variable to store the file name `$uplfile`. So, what would happen if you do this: `http://www.raphmond.com/modules/upload/attachments/<?php echo $uplfile;?>`

Comment: Man you made my day. Awsome. The first solution is now working by using http://www.raphmond.com/modules/upload/attachments/<?php echo $uplfile;?>   However your second solution still doesnot work. I guess your second solution is better because user will not be able to right clock and save the mp3. But Unfortunately only the first html5 is working.

Comment: That's OK. Please mark my answer below as the correct one if it helped you. It may also help others with a similar issue in future. My second answer should work well, regarding that you only have one <audio> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* work.

```
<audio controls src="where-you-keep-your-uploaded-file"></audio>
```

If a relative path does not work, try the full one (e.g. http://www.yourwebsite.com/music/user-file.mp3)

I once had to write a script like this, but I was using custom-made buttons to play/pause.
It was looking something like this and worked flawlessy.

HTML

```
<img alt="" onclick="music('http://www.my-website.org/media/myfile.mp3'); return false;" src="gfx/play.png"> 
<img alt="" onclick="pauseAudio(); return false;" src="gfx/pause.png"> 

<audio id="audioPlayer" src=""></audio>
```

JavaScript

```
function music(track){
   $('#audioPlayer').attr('src', track);
   $('#audioPlayer').attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
   $.get();
   }

function pauseAudio(){
   $('#audioPlayer').get(0).pause();
   }
```

Assuming that your path is actually valid, there should be no problems.

Comment: Hello, The problem is all the files that are submitted are going to the folder "http://www.yourwebsite.com/music/" and then they will be posted. The files name are by users and the website should just simply play the after upload. the dynamic address $my_base_url.$my_website_base."/modules/upload/attachments/ is doing the distinguishing between each user submission. S o It's not as simple as that

Comment: Sorry but Your answer is not helpful.

Comment: Actually, it is as simple as that. You already have the uploaded files url in the $url variable. Your src attribute should have the value of $url.

Comment: @Bob Far, ssnobody is making sense. If the file is uploaded and the path is not broken, this should work for you.

Comment: @BobFar, please don't edit my post with an attempt to solve your issue - edit your own :) For the record, try it with the complete path. You were using a relative one in your edit. Please update your post with your attempts separating the original post with the words "EDIT" and your new attempt and I will have a look.

Comment: For sure. Cuz this is the first time Im using this. Thanks.

Comment: @BobFar, I added a demo to the second example.